# How to get result populated month wise using ms access query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table which is having following structure:

```
    PID
    Year
    Month 
    LOB
    Contracts
```

Now i want to display a single row as output with selected LOB and it must have 12 column as output, each for each month(this year). Right now i am using a query which is too long which is increasing the overall time. Can anyone suggest better way to approach this kind of problem.

Comment: Try the Crosstab query wizard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
TRANSFORM COUNT([Contracts])
SELECT [LOB]
FROM [Table]
WHERE [Year]=2016 
  AND [LOB]='xxx'
GROUP BY [LOB]
PIVOT [Month] IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
```

---

To answer your comment, if you want 2 years, try this :

```
TRANSFORM COUNT([Contracts])
SELECT [LOB]
FROM [Table]
WHERE [Year] IN (2015,2016) 
  AND [LOB]='xxx'
GROUP BY [LOB]
PIVOT ([Year] & '-' & [Month]) IN
      (
       '2015-1','2015-2','2015-3','2015-4','2015-5','2015-6','2015-7','2015-8','2015-9','2015-10','2015-11','2015-12',
       '2016-1','2016-2','2016-3','2016-4','2016-5','2016-6','2016-7','2016-8','2016-9','2016-10','2016-11','2016-12'
      )
```

Comment: TRANSFORM can also do fixed values: `TRANSFORM aggfunction     selectstatement     PIVOT pivotfield [IN (value1[, value2[, …]])]` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208956%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: @Andre nice, never used this before!

Comment: @Andre, adapted :)

Comment: @ThomasG, it works perfectly for this year. What change is required, if we want data for prev year as well as this year,i.e. 24 columns ?

Comment: Thank for updating, i tried that approach. But with that 01 is showing 2015+ 2016 jan data. What i want is 24 columns with first 12 column as data for 2015 and next 12 with data for 2016

Comment: @NikhilSrivastava yes I "thought after" the answer on that one :-D Check now