# Vertical to Horizontal Table with Month Grouping

Tags: sql, ms-access

Long time lurker - first time poster.

I'm new to Access and have a data table I'm trying to manipulate via a query.

**Current View:**

```
ID  | $Value | Month   
1   | 184    | 10/1/2012    
1   | 186    | 11/1/2012     
1   | 176    | 12/1/2012     
1   | 183    | 1/1/2013     
1   | 192    | 2/1/2013     
1   | 201    | 3/1/2013     
1   | 183    | 4/1/2013     
1   | 179    | 5/1/2013     
1   | 177    | 6/1/2013     
1   | 135    | 7/1/2013     
1   | 202    | 8/1/2013     
1   | 188    | 9/1/2013     
2   | 258    | 5/1/2013     
2   | 126    | 6/1/2013     
2   | 236    | 7/1/2013     
2   | 367    | 8/1/2013     
2   | 450    | 9/1/2013     
2   | 186    | 10/1/2013     
2   | 248    | 11/1/2013     
2   | 264    | 12/1/2013     
2   | 257    | 1/1/2014     
2   | 264    | 2/1/2014     
2   | 138    | 3/1/2014     
2   | 264    | 4/1/2014
```

**Desired Ending View:**

```
ID | Month 1 | Month 2 | Month 3 | Month 4 | Month 5 | ... | Month 12    
1  | 184     | 186     | 176     | 183     | 192     | ... | 188    
2  | 258     | 126     | 236     | 367     | 450     | ... | 264
```

I'm attempting to transpose the data in Access so that there is only one row per ID and group the months (always labelled 'Month 1', 'Month 2', etc...). I only want to see 12 columns of months (Not one for each month and year). So in the above example ID 1, Month 1 is 184 and ID 2, Month 1 is 258, despite the month and year of each ID being different.

Any guidance/help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't see your images, like many of us at the office. So I can't answer. It's better to paste raw text instead. You are probaly looking for a PIVOT, check my recent answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075418/how-to-get-result-populated-month-wise-using-ms-access-query/39076318#39076318), it might help And I guess you wrongly tagged your question, it should be `sql` and not `mysql`, if so please edit and fix the tag.

Comment: ms access has a built in pivot table functionality. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Thomas G, thanks I've edited as per your suggestion and am looking into your previous answer.

Comment: @Shadow, I've tried to use it but run into trouble grouping the months

Comment: Do you expect me to use my mind reading abilities to find out what has gone wrong, or are you going to share it with us, sparing yourself from the indignity of a mind read?

Comment: @Shadow mind reading abilities would be great! Sorry, I should have elaborated. I always end up with months going out to Month 100 and something. I want to limit the months to 12. For example, in the above data set: ID 1 on 10/1/2012 and ID 2 on 5/1/2013 would both be Mo1

Comment: Then you need to explain how you come up with the 12 categories for the month values.

Comment: @CurtisMacD I edited my post to encompass your logic on months. However, i found myself making several assumptions about what you need along the way. I agree with Shadow that your requirements are not clearly defined in your post, and need to be elaborated.

Comment: @TPhe thanks, not trying to be vague on purpose - let me try to explain a little more... the 'Current View' table is populated via a form by the user. The user enters the month (always in mm/dd/yyyy form) and the amount of savings associated with a project. Access then provides a unique ID to the user and takes that savings amount ($Value) and allocates it to the next 11 months (12 months total). So if a project starts in 11/1/2013, a monthly savings amount will be shown for each month to 10/1/2013. I am now trying to transpose the 'Current View' to provide only 1 row for each ID...

Comment: At the same time I only want to see 12 columns of months (Not one for each month and year). The Pivot below from @Darren Bartrup-Cook appeared to work; however, it gave me an extra column labelled "Month" with no data in it and the Months were not in sequential order, it showed 'Month 1' 'Month 11' 'Month 12' ' Month 2' etc... I'm sure these are easy fixes but like i said, first time working in Access to this degree. Thanks again for your patience

Comment: Ok, that's a little more clear. You should edit your original post with the details. What all three of your initial answers assumed was that you wanted the month of the year - so January is month 1, Feb month 2, and so on.

Comment: Thanks @TPhe, I've updated the original post to be more clear as per your suggestion. I'll work through the pivot provided below and see if I can eliminate that extra "Month" column and organize the months as 1, 2, 3, etc...

Comment: I think my query is pretty close to what you want, but it may need some editing depending on your circumstances. I did correct the typo that was giving you an error.

Comment: @TPhe I attempted your updated query but got an "Invalid use of Null" error. It's a little over my head tbh, so having trouble troubleshooting it.

Comment: That is likely happening because in the query I am converting the Month column to a date before using the Min() function on it. The reason for this is that if your Month column is in text format, finding the Min() value will result in the lowest text - so 1/1/2014 would be before 3/1/2012 because it starts with a 1. If your column is already in date format, you could remove the cdate() function entirely, or you could change the query to remove null values: cdate(coalesce(tbl1.[Month], #1/1/2999#))

Comment: @TPhe Again appreciate your help on this, I tried both suggestions but both are returning errors. Removing cdate() returns"Invalid procedure call" and adding cdate(coalesce(tbl1.[Month], #1/1/2999#)) returns "Undefined function 'calesce' in expression"

Comment: Uh, it seems like you misspelled "coalesce" as "calesce" judging by that second error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been suggested - a crosstab (pivot) query would work here:

```
TRANSFORM   Sum(sValue) AS SumOfsValue
SELECT      ID
FROM        Table1
GROUP       BY ID
PIVOT       "Mo" & Month([dMonth])
```

Is your 'Desired Ending View' correct?
e.g. You've got 188 for ID 1 in month 12 - shouldn't this be 176?

Comment: Thanks! That's definitely getting me on the right track. and yes the ID 1 in month 12 should be 188. I'm not looking to label the months as Jan = 1, Feb = 2... I want the first month that a value is entered into to always be month 1

Comment: How do you record which month had a value entered first?  In a database the order of the records in a table are completely irrelevant so you can't use the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, ... row as the entry order.

Comment: Maybe I'm not quite explaining correctly. The database asks the user for a completion date. once that date is entered the database populates values for the following 11 months (12 Months total). The completion date entered by the user is my desired Month 1 and the next 11 months would follow in order.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with the graphical query editor interface, but you can definitely do this in SQL using the TRANSFORM and PIVOT features along with the month() function. In fact, in the graphical interface, you may just be missing the month() function. I believe the sql version would look like this:

```
TRANSFORM Max([Current View].[$Value])
SELECT  [Current View].[ID] 
from [Current View] inner join  
     ( select tbl1.[ID], min(cdate(tbl1.[Month])) as minDate
       from [Current View] as tbl1
       group by tbl1.[ID]) as earliestDate on [Current View].[ID] = earliestDate.[ID]
Where datediff("m", earliestDate.minDate, [Current View].[Month])<=12
group by [Current View].[ID]
PIVOT (datediff("m", earliestDate.minDate, [Current View].[Month]) +1 )
;
```

EDIT: Added on logic to define months based on the starting month for each ID, and restrict to only the 12 following months.

Comment: Appreciate everyone's commitment to this and apologies for being completely new to Access/sql. @TPhe this looks good, but I'm getting a syntax error in JOIN operation, any idea what might be causing that?

Comment: It looks like I left off the "r" in "earliest" one time. I've edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you have only one value per ID and month, use `FIRST` aggregate function and not `SUM` or `MAX` as proposed by my fellows.

```
TRANSFORM FIRST([$Value]) 
SELECT [ID] 
FROM [Current View] 
GROUP BY [ID] 
PIVOT "Mo" & Month([Month])
```

If you want all years and months (yyyy-mm)

```
TRANSFORM FIRST([$Value]) 
SELECT [ID] 
FROM [Current View] 
GROUP BY [ID] 
PIVOT (Year([Month]) & '-' & Month([Month]))
```

Comment: If there's only 1 value then surely `FIRST`, `SUM` and `MAX` will all return the same value?  I used `SUM` so that no figures would be excluded - if there's two entries for a month they'll get added together.  If `FIRST` or `MAX` is used it would ignore any other values entered for that month.

Comment: Yes they will return the same value indeed. It is purely logical to use FIRST here :) however if there's a data issue with a month/id duplicated, FIRST or MAX will ensure that only one value is returned. Not sure if that has any sense to SUM them in this case.

Comment: I think the idea is that generally first() will be more efficient than max() or sum(), even when it will give the same result. I buy that, though the difference would be minimal in this circumstance. As @DarrenBartrup-Cook noted, though, the poster will have to actually think this through, as first() or max() would exclude values if there happens to be more than one present for the same id and month.